# Api Integration Issue

Tags: api, integration, dml, database

I have created an api integration in salesforce. From client's website a request will send to Salesforce in form of JSON. This will create record in Salesforce. Sometimes multiple requests are sent causing duplicates. I don't have option to control from Client's website. Can you please tell do we have control in salesforce ??

Actual problem is there is some delay is insert operation. Due to this existing record checking is not performing. Hence duplication is causing.

Thanks

Comment: Suggest you to improve your question by adding more details for clarity. Please take the [Tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) and see [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info. You could control this problem at a rudimentary level using triggers, but that may not be best approach for all cases. Your question is unclear about the existing components at play here (one example to quote here : Is the external system calling standard SF web service or custom service?).

Comment: You can add Duplicate Rule on object or schedule a job that will run several times a day and clearing duplicates.

Comment: @arut I have written custom webservice class. Im new to integration, i don't know the technical terms. Please let me know what more clarifications you require.
through my custom web service class, lead and and many objects will create and update. one record will create/update at a time. It means one api request should come from client's side. But some times 2 or more requests are coming at a moment. 2nd request is entering before 1st request completes and hitting the database. at this time duplicate record is creating

Comment: @Mariia Illarionova I have checked with creating the rules, It is allowing duplicates.